# How to automatically handle "a" and "an" in front of acronyms with the glossaries package?

Tags: glossaries, languages

I am using the `glossaries` package to handle acronyms and came across the task to automatically decide the use of "a" or "an" in front of them.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,nopostdot,nomain,style=alttree,shortcuts]{glossaries}
  \setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}
  \makeglossaries
  \newacronym{sma}{sma}{SubMiniature version A}
\begin{document}
  a \ac{sma}\\ % gives "a SubMiniature version A (SMA)"
  a \ac{sma}   % gives "a SMA"
\end{document}
```

How can I achieve that the second yields "an SMA"? I do not mind indicating once for each acronym [if it needs the "n" or not](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1017) when the short form is used.

I do know about the `glossaries-prefix` package that allows to define prefixes for all the different cases (first-use, plural, singular, etc.). However, using this package, I would have to manually use its different commands (`\pgls` etc.) instead of the short acronym commands (`\ac` etc.).

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Hello, this is an interesting question! Could you please add a [short and full minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that we know what your setup is?

Comment: Since the text you want to change has nothing to do with the acronym itself, but the word before it, wouldn't you  need some sort of `\indef` macro whose form depends on the following `\ac` macro?

Comment: Can you clarify how you want this automation without using `\pgls`? As @AlanMunn commented, the `a` will need to be replaced with a command since `a \ac{sma}` can't automatically be converted into `an \ac{sma}` otherwise (`\ac` can't look behind). It's much simpler to replace `a \ac{sma}` with `\pgls{sma}` than it is to replace it with, say, `\indefinitearticle{sma} \ac{sma}` (which is essentially what `\pgls` does).

Comment: I am starting to realize that this is not feasible automatically and it really seems that I won't get out of doing this with `\pgls`. Now, I am looking for a method so that I can continue using the `\ac` commands. And it would finally be great to have a method that defaults the prefix to "a" or "an" depending on the first letter so that one only has to indicate something if this method fails. For the moment, I am struggling with non-expandable commands (especially loops) in doing this.

Comment: I posted a [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291815) to this.

Comment: There is also the question of whether to choose a or an based on the spelling of the acronym or the pronunciation: F as ef, H as aitch, L as el, M as em, etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, for sure. There is a [discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1017) I referred to in the original question. This surely cannot be done automatically for all cases but one would need to indicate the appropriate choice in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

I've started using the [`acronym`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package for this purpose. The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/acronym/acronym.pdf) shows that it defines the `\iac` (and `\Iac`) commands which automatically insert the indefinite  article in its correct form, as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help get you started:

My guess is that the ideal solution would be a massively complicated package (like the hyphenation pattern recognition for various languages) to recognize a vs an etc.  Since this isn't within my abilities here's a proposal.

If your usage with articles is truly first = Article A, and abbreviations = Article B then I would propose adding some keys to glossaries and detecting whether the acronym has been used or not to recognize which of the articles to use.

Note:  I haven't added error trapping to the command to recognize when a user tried to use the article substitution but didn't define it, but I did define the command so that the user can pass an article on an as needed basis as an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,nopostdot,nomain,style=alttree,shortcuts]{glossaries}

  \setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}


  \glsaddkey
  {article-abrv}        % new key
  {\relax}          % default value if "article-abrv" isn't used in \newglossaryentry
  {\glsentryArtA}   % analogous to \glsentrytext
  {\GlsentryArtA}   % analogous to \Glsentrytext
  {\glsArtA}        % analogous to \glstext
  {\GlsArtA}        % analogous to \Glstext
  {\GLSArtA}        % analogous to \GLStext

  \glsaddkey
  {article-long}    % new key
  {\relax}          % default value if "article-long" isn't used in \newglossaryentry
  {\glsentryArtL}   % analogous to \glsentrytext
  {\GlsentryArtL}   % analogous to \Glsentrytext
  {\glsArtL}        % analogous to \glstext
  {\GlsArtL}        % analogous to \Glstext
  {\GLSArtL}        % analogous to \GLStext


    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\aac}{o m}{%
        \IfValueTF{#1}{%
            \ifglsused{\glsentryshort{#2}}%
            {\glsdisp{#2}{#1~\ac{#2}}}%TRUE
            {\glsdisp{#2}{#1~\ac{#2}}}%FALSE
        }{%
            \ifglsused{\glsentryshort{#2}}%
            {\glsdisp{#2}{\glsArtA{#2}~\ac{#2}}}%TRUE
            {\glsdisp{#2}{\glsArtL{#2}~\ac{#2}}}%FALSE
        }%
    }

    \DeclareDocumentCommand{\Aac}{o m}{%
        \IfValueTF{#1}{%
            \ifglsused{\glsentryshort{#2}}%
            {\glsdisp{#2}{#1~\ac{#2}}}%TRUE
            {\glsdisp{#2}{#1~\ac{#2}}}%FALSE
        }{%
        \ifglsused{\glsentryshort{#2}}%
        {\glsdisp{#2}{\GlsArtA{#2}~\ac{#2}}}%TRUE
        {\glsdisp{#2}{\GlsArtL{#2}~\ac{#2}}}%FALSE
    }%
  }

  \makeglossaries

  \newacronym[article-abrv={an},article-long={a}]{sma}{sma}{SubMiniature version A}  
  \newacronym{uv}{UV}{Ultraviolet}

\begin{document}

\Aac{sma}

\Aac{sma}

Lowercase example:  \aac{sma}

Override example:  \aac[the]{sma}

%\Aac{uv}% code has no error trapping to let you use \aac as a replacement to \ac

\end{document}
```